# Splitting a row into multiple rows

Tags: stata

**UPDATED**

I am very new to Stata and I am struggling how to split a row into multiple rows

I have the following structure in my table:

```
 **particid period1 period2 v0pd20 v1pd20 v2pd20 v3pd20 v4pd20 v5pd20 v6pd20 v7pd20**
```

You can see a screenshot of it [here](http://screencast.com/t/677kl2l6D0)

How do I create a new table with the following structure based on the above

```
 **particid period pd20_0 pd20_1 pd20_2 pd20_3**
 particid period1 v0pd20 v1pd20 v2pd20 v3pd20
 particid period2 v4pd20 v5pd20 v6pd20 v7pd20
```

Based on the input from @NickCox I tried using the stack command

```
stack v0pd20 v1pd20 v2pd20 v3pd20 v4pd20 v5pd20 v6pd20 v7pd20, into (pd20_0 pd20_1 pd20_2 pd20_3)
```

It did [stack the values correctly](http://screencast.com/t/lOnKFvnCH5), but now I cannot figure out how to include the particid and create the new period-variable containing the old period1 and period2 variables.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear about the structure you are intending to end up with. Right now it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Check out the stack command.

Comment: Try using `reshape`. Please post the sample data otherwise we might be just guessing

Comment: You should include the identifier variable twice in the -stack- call.

Answer (score 0):

could use reshape:

reshape long period v, i(particid) j(visit)